# User services in FreeBSD?

Tags: services, freebsd

Say for instance I want to start up the emacs server for my user when I log in. In a systemd Linux system, I might make a unit file at `~/.config/systemd/user/emacs.service` and enable it with `systemctl --user enable emacs.service`.

Is there something equivalent in FreeBSD? Ideally, I'd like a solution that doesn't require `root` permissions.

Comment: Yes, of course, since the beginning of time but I've forgotten the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with FreeBSD specifically, but the traditional Linux/Unix way is to start things through your login shell's configuration, i.e. `~/.profile` for sh/bash/ksh or `~/.login` for csh.

That is, you just add `emacs --daemon &` somewhere near the end of your profile, optionally with a check to make sure it's not already running, or to run it only if $DISPLAY is set, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could also, just to be different, use ‘daemon’. Man daemon(8). Daemon -u user program program-arguments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Window Manager / Desktop environment, you can chooser to utilize its built in functionality.

For instance, Fluxbox can start applications on start up by configuring `~/.fluxbox/startup`

A universal way to ensure your application will auto start independent of which WM/DE you use, is it add a line inside your `~/.xinitrc` file.

If your WM/DE uses `~/.xsession` instead of `~/.xinitrc`, create a symlink to point `~/.xsession` to `~/.xinitrc`.

Editing `~/.xinitrc` will now also edit `~/.xsession`. However, it does not work in reverse. Any change in `~/.xsession` will not appear in `~/.xinitrc`. Think of it as a UDP connection, a one way street. :)

`ln -s ~/.xinitrc ~/.xsession`

To add a startup application, add a line now in `~/.xinitrc` with the specified app.

For example, too have `flameshot` auto start on startup, add the below somewhere BEFORE your WM/DE exec command in the `~/.xinitrc` file.

`flameshot &`

The `&` is very important, as without it the wanted program will run and close before continuing down your `~/.xinitrc` resulting in no open window on startup.

This is my `~/.xinitrc` for reference

```
# SET PROPER locale(1) with LC_ALL VARIABLE
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

# GTK ANTIALIASING
export GDK_USE_XFT=1

# FORCE LIBREOFFICE TO USE GTK THEME
export OOO_FORCE_DESKTOP=gnome

# QT SETTINGS
export QT_XFT=1                           # ANTIALIASING
export GTK2_RC_FILES="${HOME}/.gtkrc-2.0" # QT MUST KNOW GTK2 LOCATION
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct         # QT QT5CT

# PICOM/OPACITY
picom --config ~/.config/picom.conf &

# PRESTARTED APPS 
claws-mail &
networkmgr &
xscreensaver -no-splash &
flameshot &

# CREATE TASKBAR
fbpanel &

# SET WALLPAPER WITH FEH
~/.fehbg &

# WINDOW MANAGER
fluxbox
```

I hope this helps. :)